# combine multiple reports in crystal reports in c#

Tags: crystal-reports

I have designed a crystalReport(myReport.rpt) that is connected to data base without any problem. What I want is to create a report including multiple of this report...!

For example creating a 3-pages report that each page is built by myReport.rpt but with different values...
In fact I want to create some objects from my report class and then combine all of them to be one report and I print that or make pdf from that...

Example:

```
myReport rpt1= new myReport();   //(some changes in rpt1's fields):
(TextObject)rpt1.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["time"]).Text=getTime();
((TextObject)rpt1.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["date"]).Text =getDate();
// or any other changes in fileds

myReport rpt2= new myReport();  //(some changes in rpt2's fields):
(TextObject)rpt2.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["time"]).Text = getTime();
((TextObject)rpt2.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["date"]).Text = getDate();
 // or any other changes in fileds...

myReport rpt3= new myReport();  //(some changes in rpt3's fields):
(TextObject)rpt3.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["time"]).Text = getTime();
((TextObject)rpt3.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["date"]).Text = getDate();
// or any other changes in fileds...
```

and I want something like this:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument totalReport=new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
totalReport=merge(rpt1,rpt2,rpt3);
totalReport.PrintToPrinter(1, ture, 1, 1);
```

Thank you for your helping...
I'm using:
VS 2012 & Crystal Reports 13

Comment: you can do that by arranging into subreports